# Migrar una aplicación móvil hecha en Visual Studio 2010 y pasarla a Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio

Tengo una aplicación móvil de Android, hecha en *Visual Studio 2010*, pero quiero compilarla en *Visual Studio 2015*. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: No se de Visual Studio, ¿pero no hay una opción para importar un proyecto? Si ya lo hiciste, ¿Te mandó errores de compatibilidad o similares?

Comment: esta la opcion convertir pero que crees no me deja hacer nada no me da opciones :/